# Issue of Update data into SQLite database

Tags: iphone

I am doing updation in SQLite database. When I am updating single data (means AcountName of the database field it is updating prooerly). But when I am updating multiple fields together (like AcountName,UserName,Password, Url, Note any of the combination with AcountName then application gets crashed at **sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update UserInfo1 set AcountName=?, UserName=?, Password=?, Url=?, Note=? where AcountName='%@'",strAcountName];**)

```
-(void)updateData:(NSString *)AcName :(NSString *)UsrName :(NSString *)Pswd :(NSString *)url :(NSString *)Note
{
   sqlite3_stmt *updateStatement = nil;
   NSString *sql;
   int returnvalue;

   sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update UserInfo1 set AcountName=?, UserName=?, Password=?, Url=?, Note=? where AcountName='%@'",strAcountName];

   returnvalue = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &updateStatement, NULL);

   if (returnvalue == 1)
   {
      NSAssert1 (0,@"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
   }

   sqlite3_bind_text(updateStatement, 1,[AcName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

   sqlite3_bind_text(updateStatement, 2,[UsrName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

   sqlite3_bind_text(updateStatement, 3,[Pswd UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

   sqlite3_bind_text(updateStatement, 4,[url UTF8String],-1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

   sqlite3_bind_text(updateStatement, 5,[Note UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

   if(sqlite3_step(updateStatement) != SQLITE_DONE )
   {
       bulDataExist = YES;
       [strAcountName retain];
   }
   else
   {
       sqlite3_reset(updateStatement);
       bulDataExist = NO;
   }
   sqlite3_finalize(updateStatement);
}
 Sent at 6:11 PM on Tuesday
```

Please correct me.

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated -- but the way you are constructing the `sql` statement is vulnerable to SQL injection (eg. manually surrounding a variable with quotes).  Instead, you should probably bind the strAcountName value into the statement the same way you are binding the other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you have something bad in strAcountName.  I'd bet it got autoreleased before you got to it.  Call

```
[strAcountName retain]
```

after you create it, then call

```
[strAcountName release]
```

when you're done with it.  And why do you retain it after a successful sql update?  I'd think you'd be tossing it at that point.

Comment: Thanks @Owen....problem was at the time of selecting & displaying data i had to retain this instead in this block.